# Please help me identify these seeds I found in my vegetable garden - ZONE 10A, Southwest Florida

Tags: identification

This is my first post here. I'm glad I found this forum. I live in South West Florida, Zone 10a. I went out to check on my vegetable garden this morning and found three seeds a squirrel or bird must have dropped into my peppers and tomatoes. Can anyone help me identify them? One was a very dark black with orange on the tip/end, the other looked reddish with the orange tip like the other, and then I found this dark red one with what looked like the same black seed poking out of the outer red shell as what I found in the garden. I'm assuming all 3 are the same seed. At first glance, I thought it was a Rosary Pea, but since there seems to be a soft (I didn't touch it) reddish outer shell and the orange coloration, I've determined I don't think that's the case (thank God). Please see the photos. Any input would be appreciated. I want to know if they're poisonous and what I should do now with my vegetable garden if that's the case. I used my trowel to pick them up, bagged them up and threw them away.

[image: red seed]
[image: red seed]
[image: black seed]

Comment: The mere presence of a poisonous seed (or poisonous plant, for that matter) does not poison your other plants. Just remove the seed (or resulting plant) and don't ingest it. We get "deadly nightshade" all the time in my area. If nobody eats it, nobody dies from it. Some folks even deliberately grow it since it's pretty, or goth, or pretty goth... If it is "rosary pea" that appaers to offer no particular issue if you don't eat it (considering how it got that name, handling them does not seem to be dangerous) https://plants.ifas.ufl.edu/plant-directory/abrus-precatorius/

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yeah, my neighbor liked the pretty flowers and berries of pokeweed and never deadheaded it (or better yet, dug it up), so I would always get dozens of pokeweed seedlings in my vegetable garden. It was only an issue when the pokeweed sprouted among the spinach, because they can mimic spinach seeds for awhile. I'd just pull up the seedlings when I saw them (or when they got bigger than the spinach) and never had a problem.